# Chrome: more apps shortcut per row

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, google-chrome-extensions

Google Chrome's "Apps" page contains up to 24 app shortcuts per page arranged as four rows with six shortcuts per row. My monitor screen resolution is 1920 x 1080 so I have a lot of white space on both sides of the shortcuts.

I am trying to have ten app shortcuts per row, which would then allow me to have a total of forty shortcuts per page. I have googled a lot but haven't been able to find any solutions.

Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps something like [Speed Dial](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/speed-dial/dgpdioedihjhncjafcpgbbjdpbbkikmi) is what you're looking for?

Comment: @Karan I am not looking for speed dial...

Comment: +1 for a more customizable chrome